# Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{F}^4$ such that... - checking my answer!

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is the same as one previously asked, but I can't comment so I had to ask my own. [Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{F}^4$ such that $\mathbb{F}^4 = U \oplus W$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771961/find-a-subspace-w-of-mathbbf4-such-that-mathbbf4-u-oplus-w?rq=1)

Suppose $U=\{ (u_1,u_1,u_2,u_2)\in \mathbb{F}^4:u_1,u_2\in \mathbb{F}\}$.
Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{F}^4$ such that $\mathbb{F}^4 = U\oplus W$.

I chose $W = \{ (0,w_1,0,w_2)\in \mathbb{F}^4:w_1,w_2\in \mathbb{F}\}$.
Is this incorrect or can I use it just as previous answers have been $(0,w_1,w_2,0)$?

From what I can tell, my answer allows $U\cap W = \{0\}$ and $U+W=\{(u_1,u_1+w_1,w_1,u_2+w_2)\in\mathbb{F}^4:u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2\in\mathbb{F}\}=\mathbb{F}^4$.

Is this a sufficient argument?

Comment: Could  you link the other question? Some one else might run into the same problem as you and find this question useful.

Comment: Can someone define $\mathbb{F}$ for me? I've never seen this notation before.

Comment: My text defines $\mathbb{F}$ to be either of the fields $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that $U\oplus W=\Bbb{F}^4$. Indeed $U\cap W=\{0\}$, but the space $U+W$ consists of *all* sums of vectors from $U$ and $W$. That is
\begin{eqnarray*}
U+W&=&\{u+w:\ u\in U,\ w\in W\}\\
&=&\{(u_1,u_1,u_2,u_2)+(0,w_1,0,w_2):\ u_1,u_2\in\Bbb{F},\ w_1,w_2\in\Bbb{F}\}\\
&=&\{(u_1,u_1+w_1,u_2,u_2+w_2):\ u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2\in\Bbb{F}\}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So, loosely speaking, you shouldn't only look at sums of vectors with the same $x$ and $y$, but at all pairs of vectors from $U$ and $W$.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to grad school this fall, taking linear algebra 2 without having had an undergrad course in the field. I am using text and doing exercises to be prepared. I think I see that you mean that my $x,y\in\mathbb{F}$ are not arbitrary enough given the two subspaces and you have named them differently. Should it be $(u_1,u_1+w_1,u_2,u_2+w_2)$ in the last line of the equation array?

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely!

Comment: Trying now to find a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^5$ such that $\mathbb{F}^5=U\oplus W$ when $U=\{(u_1,u_2,u_1+u_2,u_1-u_2,2u_1)\in \mathbb{F}^5:u_1,u_2\in\mathbb{F}\}$.  

I have $W=\{(0,0,w_1,w_1,w_1)\in\mathbb{F}^5:w_1\in\mathbb{F}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provide doesn't work. The vector $(1,1,1,1)\in \mathbb{F}^4$ but can't be written as $(x,2x,y,2y)$. But you can still solve your problem by taking the orthogonal complement $W^{\bot}$ of $W$. With $W$ as defined, its orthogonal complement is given by:$$W^{\bot}=\left\lbrace X=(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{F}^4\mid\,\langle X,v\rangle=0,\mbox{ for all }v\in W \right\rbrace ,$$
where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ represents the usual inner product of $\mathbb{F}^4$.

On the orther hand, we can write 
$$W=\mbox{span}
\left\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rbrace
.$$ 
Therefore $X=(x,y,z,t)\in W^{\bot}$ if and only if:
\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\overline{x}=-\overline{y}\\
\overline{z}=-\overline{t}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
This system provides
$$W^{\bot}=\mbox{span}
\left\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
-1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rbrace
.$$ 
You can immediately check that $W\oplus W^{\bot}=\mathbb{F}^4$.

Comment: I am only in the first chapter of the book and know nothing of spans or orthogonal complements, so what you have shown is a little foreign to me still. Does my edit of the example I have make a difference?