# Find a subspace W of F4 such that F4=U⊕W

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution has been given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771961/find-a-subspace-w-of-mathbbf4-such-that-mathbbf4-u-oplus-w)

Suppose $U = \{(x,x,y,y) \in \mathbb{F}^4 : x, y \in \mathbb{F}\}$

I understand that we first need to construct a $W$ that the sum is $F^4$ and show that $U\cap W=0$.

My question is it seems that after I constructed the $W$, $U\cap W=0$ should be true. Am I correct? Or there are some cases where it won't be true?

Comment: Are you asking if $F^{4}=U+W$ automatically implies $U\cap W=\{0\}$? That is not true since $W$ can be $F^{4}$.

Comment: I should be more specific. How about suppose: Suppose U={(x,x,y,y)∈F4:x,y∈F}