# Direct sum problem linear algebra done right

Tags: linear-algebra

Very confused on how to deal with these direct sum problems.

Problem:Suppose $U=\{(x,y,x+y,x-y,2x) \in \mathbb{F}^{5}:x,y \in \mathbb{F}\}$

Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{F}^{5}$ such that $\mathbb{F}^{5}=U \oplus W$

Trying to figure out a routine way to do these problems. I used the following link to help [Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{F}^4$ such that $\mathbb{F}^4 = U \oplus W$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771961/find-a-subspace-w-of-mathbbf4-such-that-mathbbf4-u-oplus-w)

Attempt:

Given $(a,b,c,d,e) \in \mathbb{F}^{5}$,

$(a,b,c,d,e)=(a,b,a+b+c-a-b,a-b-a+b+d,2a-2a+e)$

$=(a,b,a+b,a-b,2a)+(0,0,c-a-b,-a+b+d,e-2a)$

where $(a,b,a+b,a-b,2a) \in U$ and $(0,0,c-a-b,-a+b+d,e-2a) \in W$

Hence $\mathbb{F}^{5}=U+W$

Next Show $U \cap W=\{0\}$

Attempt:

Let $(e,f,g,h,i) \in U \cap W$ then $e=0,f=0$

I can't seem to figure out why $g=0,h=0,i=0$

Also is this the correct way to approach this type of problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since $U=\text{span}\left(\left\{\right(1,0,1,1,2), \, (0,1,1,-1,0)\}\right)$ so to find a $W$, one can choose $W=U^{\perp}$ (orthogonal complement of $U$), i.e. 
$$W=\{v \in \Bbb{F}^5 \, | \, \forall u \in U, \,\,  v \cdot u = 0\}.$$
In this particular problem, (using the basis vectors of $U$)
$$W=\{(x,y,z,s,t) \, | \, x+z+s+2t=0 \text{ and } y+z-s=0\}.$$
Thus we need the basis vectors for the solution set of 
\begin{align*}
x+ z+s+2t & =0\\
y+z-s & =0.
\end{align*}
The solutions are given by
$$W=\{(-z-s-2t,-z+s,z,s,t) \, | \, z,s,t \in \Bbb{F}\}.$$
OR
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}=z\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
$$W=\text{Span}\left(\left\{(-1,-1,1,0,0), \, (-1,1,0,1,1),\, \, (-2,0,0,0,1)\right\}\right).$$

Since $W=U^{\perp}$, so $U \cap W=\{0\}$ is an easy outcome of that.

Comment: That's a pretty methodical approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your answer panning out.

Here's another method:

$U$ is the span of $\{(1,0,1,1,2), (0,1,1,-1,0)\}$. (To see this, plug in $x=1,y=0$, and $x=0, y=1$, to get two obviously l.i. vectors in $U$.  But $U$ is clearly two-dimensional: two free variables.)

So the problem can be boiled down to expanding this to a basis of $\Bbb F^5$.

You could use the "sifting algorithm", applied to a generating set (most easily just adjoin the standard basis to the two vectors above to get a basis). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/465913/403337).

Comment: Would I also have to say $W=\{(0,0,w,z,s) \in \mathbb{F}^{5}:w,z,s \in \mathbb{F}\}$ using different variables from $x$ and $y$?Then is the problem finished?

Comment: Let me look at it some more.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: My first attempt was wrong.  I don't see where yours is going.  I have provided an alternate route,  if you're still interested.

Comment: I would like to see the alternative route

Comment: It's straight forward.   Did you look at the link?

Comment: Now I see it. My bad

Comment: If I'm not mistaken,  you can adjoin $\{e_1,e_2, e_5\}$ to get a basis.